# Stripe integration in a Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have an app where I am trying to integrate stripe API. I'm using the keys I'm getting in my test account and it seems like it's not working at all. It's giving me the following error

This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key.

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you used the key that starts with `sk_` or the `pk_`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using your Publishable API key to perform an action such as charging a customer. Publishable API keys are only used to create payment tokens.

https://stripe.com/docs/keys

> There are also two types of API keys: publishable and secret.
>
> - Publishable API keys are meant solely to identify your account with Stripe, they aren’t secret. In other words, they can safely be published in places like your Stripe.js JavaScript code, or in an Android or iPhone app. Publishable keys only have the power to [create tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token).
> - Secret API keys should be kept confidential and only stored on your own servers. Your account’s secret API key can perform any API request to Stripe without restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Secret key" of stripe for use stripe in laravel.